# use joomla logined user data in another php file

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i'm new to joomla. i would to use logined joomla user info in my php file. i use the following code to do this:

in the following code i would to echo logined user name:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', "/wamp/www/joomla" );
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( 'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( 'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( 'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$theUser =&JFactory::getUser();
echo $theUser;
```

but when i execute this, the following error occures:

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www\joomla\chklogintest.php on line 9
```

the line 9 which caused error is:

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

can anyone help me please? how can i solve this? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all "&" characters, variable assigned by reference has been deprecated in PHP. You can read the manuel page for further information : 
[Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Be careful if you upgrade your version of php it might raise a fatal error.